# UrlGenerationError in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, null

I've searched this site and asked a couple other programmers and can't figure out what the problem is with my code.  I'm a beginner to Rails, so I'm still trying to figure everything out.

I'm getting this error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Lists#show
>
> No route matches {:action=>"toggle_completed", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil, :list_id=>3} missing required keys: [:id]

Here is the code it's referring to on the Lists#show page:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h3>add a task</h3>
 <%= render 'tasks/form', task: Task.new() %>
<p>
  <strong>List Name:</strong>
  <%= @list.name %><p></p>
  <%  @list.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <td><%= task.id %></td>
    <td><%= task.name %></td>
    <td><%= task.completed %></td>
    <td><%= link_to('Toggle', toggle_completed_list_task_path(:list_id => @list.id,
:id => task.id), :method => :put ) %></td><br />
  <% end %>
</p>
```

My Routes:

```
  resources :lists do
    resources :tasks do
      member do
        put :toggle_completed
      end
    end
  end
```

Tasks Controller:

```
  def toggle_completed
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.completed = !@task.completed
    @task.save
  end
```

List has_many: tasks
and
Task belongs_to: list

I've experimented a bit and on my Lists#show page, if I add this line:

```
<%= task.id %>
```

The correct value appears on the page, so I'm not sure why it's coming up nil.  I've searched the site and haven't found anything that really discusses this exact issue.  Thanks!

Comment: By any chance are you creating any new instance of `list.tasks` in show action

Comment: Because in that case you will get a new initialized instance in `@list.tasks` with no `id`

Comment: Hello Deepak.  I'm not sure.  I do have a form on that page for creating a new task.  I'll edit the original post and add the code from the entire show.html.erb page

Comment: Deepak, I think you figured out what the issue was.  On my Lists#show page, I'm rendering a form and on that form, I'm using @list.tasks.build. I think that was initializing the instance, so that makes sense!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

create a separate routes for `toggle_completed` ex-

```
 put 'list/task/:id', to: 'tasks#toggle_completed', as: :list_task_completed
```

and

```
<%= link_to('Toggle', list_task_completed_path(:id => task.id), :method => :put ) %>
```

Comment: `list_task_completed_path` if this is not your routes you can search your own routes in your by running command `rake routes | grep toggle_completed`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I added your code with the new route, but I'm still getting a URLGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"toggle_completed", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Sorry its my mistake i have changed the answer , instead of get write put in routes. Please try this